# Angular Material mat-stepper, how to pass programmatically created componentRefs to mat-step correctly?

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, angular-material, mat-stepper

I have a question please,
I created programmatically some components which only was declared, so those selectors not used in any template at all. I used `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` to create the component each creation result is a `ComponentRef`. I put those into an array.
I passed that `ComponentRef` array into my component which wrapping the `mat-stepper`. I made an `*ngFor` with the array it can be ok, but
how can I set the template part below the `mat-step`?
Came to my mind, I can do anyway with `ngTemplateOutlet`, just need a template reference which can come from `componentRef.instance` if I capture it with `ViewChild` below the page what I would like to show for example.
I don't know how can I set below the `mat-step` the template from the `componentRef`.

If somebody has any Idea could you please share with me?

Thank you in advance.